# Alteryx separate the first integer of a number and put it in a new column

Tags: alteryx

I only have one column that has an 8-digit number. No dots, commas or any conjugation. Only integers.
I simply want to extract the **first** integer from the number and put it to a new column named "First integer". I want the rest of the integers, untouched, to either go to a new column as they are, or stay in the existing column but without the first integer

for example now I have: columnA: 23456789

I want         First Integer:2    columnA: 3456789

I am pretty new to Alteryx so that might even be a ridiculous question to some :P
But any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose `[i]` is the relevant numeric field in your Alteryx workflow.

Then using a Formula tool, this expression will give the first digit:

```
[i]/POW(10,FLOOR(LOG10([i])))
```

And this will give the remaining digits:

```
MOD([i],POW(10,FLOOR(LOG10([i]))))
```

Explanation: working inside-out: Log10([i]) tells you how many powers of 10 you're working with, FLOOR just rounds that off, POW(10,...) multiplies it back out... so basically for an 8 digit number, this gives 10,000,000.  Then you simply divide to get the first digit, or take the MOD (modulus) to get the remaining digits.

PS, your question mentions an 8-digit integer... if you are absolutely certain that your integers always have 8 digits (and the first digit is not a zero), then you can shortcut this: firstDigit=`[i]/10000000` and remainingDigits=`MOD([i],10000000`).

Comment: Thanks John! that helped!